# Silverlight Dispatcher event queue order

Tags: silverlight, dispatcher

Is the Silverlight Dispatcher event queue's ordering strictly preserved?

To elaborate: If I have exactly one other thread calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, is it guaranteed that those calls will be processed on the UI thread in the same order, or is the ordering nondeterministic?

Comment: Its funny, this exact question has been asked before and recently but I can't find it now.  Exact same answer is given.

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms591206.aspx):

> If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made
>   at the same DispatcherPriority, they
>   will be executed in the order the
>   calls were made.

so, yes, if the same thread is queueing the messages, they will be executed in the order they are queued. That's assuming Silverlight follows the same rules (I'm assuming it does but it does not include an accessible `DispatcherPriority`) and the MSDN docs for Silverlight's `BeginInvoke` are rather light.